# jQuery namespacing using objects and self executing anonymous functions

Tags: jquery, namespaces

I am looking at creating namespace using objects and self executing anonymous functions. Which one is considered a better option?

Using objects, is giving a unique name 'myAppName' enough to prevent collisions?

```
var myAppName = { 
    val1: "abc", 
    val2: "xyz",
    myFunc1: function() {
      return this.val2;  
    }
}

console.log(myAppName.val1);  // abc
console.log(myAppName.myFunc1());  // xyz
```

Using self executing anonymous function:

```
(function () {
val1 = "abc";
    var val2 = "xyz";

    myFunc1 = function() {
        return val1;   
    }

    var myFunc2 = function() {
        return val2;
    }
})();

console.log(val1);  // abc
console.log(myFunc1());  // abc
console.log(myFunc2());  // xyz
```

In the above code for self executing function, they all seem to execute. Is there a meaning of using and not using var before the variables and function names? I don't quite get it. Is there a way to make the variables and functions private and public? or is everything inside the self executing function is private?

What happens if I use 'var' before the self executing function like below?

```
var myAppName = (function () {
val1 = "abc";
    var val2 = "xyz";

    myFunc1 = function() {
        return val1;   
    }

    var myFunc2 = function() {
        return val2;
    }
})();
```

Comment: In you second code block, the call to `console.log(myFunc2());` will not display `xyx`. Instead, it will throw `ReferenceError: myFunc2 is not defined`. That is because `myFunc2` is local to the anonymous function.

Comment: In your third code block, `myAppName` will be `undefined` because you are not returning anything from the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My first answer tried to address your original questions and show how to set up a namespace. Instead of adding to that answer, I decided to add a second answer to address the questions in your comment to my first answer.

Global variables are really properties of the `window` object. If you use `var` outside of a function, you are defining a global variable. If you use `var` inside a function, you are defining a local variable. If you reference a variable `someValue` without declaring it with `var`, it is the same as referencing `window.someValue`.

The following code shows the different ways to set a global variable, and the one way to define a local variable.

```
window.global1 = 'abc';
global2 = 'def';
var global3 = "ghi";

(function() {
    window.global4 = 'jkl';
    global5 = 'mno';
    var local1 = 'xyz';
})();

console.log(global1); // 'abc'
console.log(global2); // 'def'
console.log(global3); // 'ghi'
console.log(global4); // 'jkl'
console.log(global5); // 'mno'
console.log(local1);  // ReferenceError: local1 is not defined
```

In general, you want to limit setting global variables (at least when creating a JavaScript library). A namespace is basically just a global variable. When you place everything else under that namespace, you have added only a single global variable.

I think it is also a best practice to avoid setting global variables like `global2` and `global5` above. Instead, you should use `var` oustide of a function (like `global3`) or set a property on the `window` object (like `global1` and `global4`).

Borrowing the code example from my other answer, we can create a namespace like this:

```
var myApp = (function() {
    var privateValue = 'abc'; // Don't forget "var" here.

    function privateFunction() {
        return privateValue;
    }

    return {
        publicValue: 'xyz',

        publicFunction: function() {
            return privateFunction();
        }
    }
})();
```

We could have achieved the same by doing the following, but I consider this bad style:

```
(function() {
    var privateValue = 'abc'; // Don't forget "var" here.

    function privateFunction() {
        return privateValue;
    }

    myApp = {
        publicValue: 'xyz',

        publicFunction: function() {
            return privateFunction();
        }
    }
})();
```

In both cases we have set up the `myApp` global variable, but I think it is much clearer in the former than in the latter.

Just to be clear, in both cases we would address the public variable as `myApp.publicValue` and call the public function using `myApp.publicFunction()`, and outside of the anonymous function we would not be able to reference `privateValue` or `privateFunction`.

Answer (score 4):

Putting all of your code under a single namespace is certainly going to help avoid name collisions. If you do have a collision, it will be much easier to change your code to deal with it.

Your first code example is fine if everything needs to be public. If you want some things to be private, use an anonymous, immediately executed function, like this:

```
var myApp = (function() {
    var privateValue = 'abc'; // Don't forget "var" here.

    function privateFunction() {
        return privateValue;
    }

    return {
        publicValue: 'xyz',

        publicFunction: function() {
            return privateFunction();
        }
    }
})();
```

Notice how the anonymous function returns an object that contains the public variables and functions. If you don't put "var" before "privateValue", then you are not defining a local variable; Instead, you are referencing a global variable (which is really a property of the "window" object.)

If you are using jQuery, I recommend the following:

```
(function(window, $, undefined) {

    var myApp = (function() {
        var privateValue = 'abc'; // Don't forget "var" here.

        function privateFunction() {
            return privateValue;
        }

        return {
            publicValue: 'xyz',

            publicFunction: function() {
                return privateFunction();
            }
        }
    })();

    // Put myApp in the global scope.
    window.myApp = myApp; 

})(window, jQuery);
```

This way, you are safe to use `$()` instead of `jQuery()`. You are also safe to treat `undefined` as a constant. You can also more easily deal with the situation where someone has overridden the window object.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a difference between doing `(function () {` and `var myApp = (function () {`? Or is it the same thing? I guess in the former, I access the variable or function like this: `console.log(val1);` and in the latter like this: `console.log(myApp.val1);`. Is that right? Any other difference apart from that?

Comment: @user1448031 - I have added another answer that hopefully answers your questions.